# Soudcloud iframe widget customization

Tags: javascript, html, css, soundcloud

I am trying to adjust the soundcloud embed widget but am having some difficulty. I would like to do two things:

1) Override the CSS for the div.sc-truncate ( overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap ) which contains the text "Wanderlust Basement Tapes" but will currently not display the entire text due to the aforementioned text. I have added my own style to the site stylesheet with !important but they seem to have no effect which I think has to do with the widget being an iframe.

2) Force the widget layout proportions to show full song list by default. Normally this requires scrolling to the bottom of the list. Ex:

[image: Widget 1]

vs

[image: Widget 2]

I'm guessing that the proportions change after scrolling via some javascript but all the javascript being used by the widget is minified as far as I can tell and is thus difficult to analyze and/or modify. For this reason I am hoping that a developer of the widget will be able to recommend a possible method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to modify the styles of any page in an iframe from the containing document (including the SoundCloud widget).

Having it spread over two lines does look pretty fine in this case, but obviously title lengths of all sizes also need to be considered. I will pass on the request to investigate removing the truncation.

Comment: Thanks! In the mean time is there any particular function in the widget's JavaScript that I can call to force the full song list to be visible by default? To sort of simulate having scrolled to the bottom of the list.